# jQuery.ajax (json) not working in IE (Mime Mismatch?!)

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer

I am using the following code to call data from Google Finance, in IE i receive the following error:

```
SEC7112: Script from http://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=SHMN,^DJI,^IXIC,^BSESN,^SPX,^FTSE&callback=jQuery16103746164922384498_1310730350943&_=1310730352607 was blocked due to mime type mismatch investors
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/c2VeD/

How would i rectify this issue ?!

Comment: It works fine in my IE8. What version have you tested?

Comment: @Sangdol i am testing using IE9 with browser modes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like same issue with [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/27/ie9-beta-google-image-search-javascript-content-type-and-nosniff.aspx):

> As I mentioned earlier this month, IE9 will not execute script if the
>   HTTP response headers specify X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff and do
>   not specify one of the following Content-Types: ["text/javascript",
>   "application/javascript", "text/ecmascript", "application/ecmascript",
>   "text/x-javascript", "application/x-javascript", "text/jscript",
>   "text/vbscript", "text/vbs"].

Google Finance's HTTP response headers have `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` and MIME type is `text/html`. You can't fix this. You may have to send mail to google about this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to host the script yourself somewhere to get around this issue in IE9

As the issue doesn't exist with IE8 (the actual version not IE9 emulation) You might want to just test it with IE8 on another machine